# How to reduce timeout for bad password on disconnected laptop?

Tags: active-directory, login, timeout, windows-7

I use a Windows 7 laptop computer.  When not attached to my AD domain, if I enter an incorrect password, I have to wait approximately a full minute before the failure response comes back.

When attached to the domain, the response is instant.  I think that what's happening is that is that when my entry fails against the cached pw, Windows tries to reach the domain controller and the timeout for that operation is about 60s.

Is there a registry entry that controls the timeout?  I'd love to reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are remotely severed from your AD environment but still have a network link, Windows will attempt to perform the DNS SRV record lookup to find a Domain Controller to verify your credentials. Easiest way would be to suspend any network connection, and Windows should not attempt to locate the DNS SRV records for a DC.

Comment: essentially not be connected to any network and it would time out faster.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS timeout issue... Check your resolver list when you are offline and make sure the DNS servers are responding. If the laptop is doing a SRV query and waiting for a non-responsive DNS server to respond before finally timing out and checking the pw cache, that would cause this kind of effect.